# How to find out Connected Clients Ip Address in grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I am doing small project on grails. I am trying to add networking concepts in this projects can u please guide how to work on it

**Requirement:-**

> I am running my project in my localhost(http://localhost:8080/xyz).So if another person is accessing the project  with the same localhost(http://192.168.x.x:8080/xyz).By using the networking concept i should get  the details  of that particular users ip address who using with the same localhost (IP address).

currently i am using this query to get IP address of my system

```
${request.getScheme()}:${InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()}
```

but i want IP address of particular user who are using this project in network.

please guide me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just be able to use:

```
String addr = request.remoteAddr
```

Comment: Are you connecting from the Localhost?

Comment: i dont want 127.0.0.1 ......i need others ip address who are in LAN.....like 192.168.x.xx2

Comment: If you are viewing your website by going to `localhost:8080` in your browser, then the IP address you are connecting with is `127.0.0.1`.  Have you tried connecting via the browser on another machine?  Have you seen that that gives you a different value?

Comment: is there any other way to retrieve a ip address of particular user in localhost?

Comment: No.  If you are connecting to localhost, then by definition, you are on the localhost ip, so your ip is `127.0.0.1`.  The same as anyone behind a proxy, you will get the IP address of the proxy, not the client machine

Comment: PS:  This is not a groovy or grails thing, this is a basic computer networking thing