# Grails find public IP address of the session user

Tags: grails

I am using grails and I want to find the public IP of the session user, so that I can locate there location country.

I am using:

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()
```

to get the ip but the problem is that it gives me the private ip i.e 192.168.X.X which is of no use.

Thanx in advance

Comment: See -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140859/how-do-you-get-client-ip-address-in-a-grails-controller

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763338/how-to-find-out-connected-clients-ip-address-in-grails

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you just need to use

```
InetAdress.getHostAddress()
```

But you can just use the request?

```
request.getRemoteAddr()
```

Within a session you can also use

```
String ipAddr = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
       .getRequest().getRemoteAddr();
```

Comment: Thanx for the quick reply :) But none of these are working. Only request.getRemoteAddr() is giving value something like 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 which of no use.

Comment: @Charsee You're looking at a site running on your local machine yeah?  That you are connecting via the local host.  Try looking at the output of `request.remoteAddr` when viewing the site from a different computer...

Comment: thanx tim and niels for the help :)  Its working now on main server