# Find public IP address of the session user in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, get, request, ip-address

I want to request the remote address of the session user in grails. I found a question here which describes the problem ([Grails find public IP address of the session user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135467/grails-find-public-ip-address-of-the-session-user)) and the answer really works. I use only request.getRemoteAddr() and I receive 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 in my localhost.However, what I have to do to see the real IP address of the user?

In this previous question which I have found it is said "Try looking at the output of request.remoteAddr when viewing the site from a different computer". I really don't know what this means and I need your help here. I can load the server only in my own browser and I use "localhost:8080/..."
Please,tell me how and where to get the correct request. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

> "Try looking at the output of request.remoteAddr when viewing the site
>   from a different computer"

means that you will need to connect to the application running on your machine from another machine in your LAN.
If you have another machine in your LAN, you will need to find your local network IP address (use ipconfig) and from the other machine connect to this address. For example if your IP is `192.168.0.2`, connect to `http://192.168.0.2:8080`

As tim_yates mentioned `request.getRemoteAddr()` may not always return the correct address  due to dynamic addressing and proxy servers. However you **may** find the original address from various HTTP headers such as: `HTTP_CLIENT_IP, HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR, HTTP_X_FORWARDED`
Take a look at the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527638/getting-the-client-ip-address-remote-addr-http-x-forwarded-for-what-else-coul) which provides more information about this subject.

Answer (score 0):

That's the best you're going to get.

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
```

Is your local address. Also, this cannot be guaranteed to be unique to a user due to dynamic addressing and proxy servers